# Use Lucene in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I'm wondering how can I use Lucene for searching and indexing with PHP, Google said that I can do so just if It will be through Zend framework, this latter unlikely does not present in my dictionary, I use standard PHP, can I use Zend just for get Lucene work on my site for indexing my e-books?
I'm using Netbeans 6.8 for information, and I found this word 'Zend' (all what I know about is his name ^^) in somewhere on Netbeans options.
Really can't understand what some sites suggest, please help! and give me the simplest way to get started and then I'll take the wheel! 
Thanks in advance,
Regards!

Comment: You can use Zend_Lucene without using the rest of the Zend Framework.  However, from personal experience I don't recommend using Zend_Lucene on large indexes -- it performs at a fraction of the speed of solr.  FOr a small project with an index no larger than a few hundred documents, it can be convenient.

Comment: Very interesting that I can use Zend_Lucene without using the rest of the Zend Framework. just a quest: which one is easier in term of his configuration in my project? Zend_Lucene or Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) has a REST API which could be used from PHP, or any language for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Sphinx or Lucene/Solr directly. Zend_Lucence works OK for small projects, but is not as fast as Sphinx or Solr.